# É possível ter interação ao atualizar a minha app?

Tags: android

Como é que eu posso alterar `sharedPreferences` ou adicionar uma pasta no momento da atualização da minha app?

Eu tenho uma app em C que estou a correr em Android com a biblioteca SDL e sempre que eu faço uma atualização da app os ficheiros da aplicação têm de ser atualizados também (estão numa pasta do sistema). O problema é que eu não sei quando é que foi feita uma atualização.

Eu sei que ao inicializar a app consigo fazer isso, mas não deixa de ser uma gambiarra e pode haver problemas se o utilizador não abrir a app até a próxima atualização. Se houvesse forma de fazer durante a instalação era o ideal e resolvia todos os problemas.

Comment: Faça uma verificação sempre que a aplicação abrir, se existir a pasta deixe como está, se não existir, cria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Não é possível.

Terás de esperar a próxima vez que a aplicação seja executada e então fazer isso.

A única possibilidade é teres, em outra *package*, um *BroadcastReceiver* que responda aos *Intents* [ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED) e [ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED) e execute um serviço da aplicação instalada/actualizada que faça a actualização desses ficheiros.

O método `onReceive()` do *BradcastReceiver* seria algo assim:

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    final String action = intent.getAction();

    if (action.equals(Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED)) {
        Uri data = intent.getData();
        String pkgName = data.getEncodedSchemeSpecificPart();
        if(pkgName.equals("nome da package"){
            //Executar serviço para terminar a instalação
        }
    }

    //Testar intent ACTION_PACKAGE_CHANGED
    ....
    ....
}
```

O problema é se essa *package* for desinstalada....

Comment: Se entretanto não aparecer nenhuma resposta marco a tua.